help: yasnippets won't load table
I'm having trouble with yasnippets. I install it but it won't work -- it does not expand anything. When I do yas-describe-table-by-namehash it lists
"Snippet table LaTex-mode" "Snippet table latex-mode"
and under both shows all the proper snippets. But "yas-describe-tables" shows blank tables. I test by opening a .tex file typing "tt" and hitting tab to expand. Or typing "tt" and M-x yas-expand
I have tried with and without "(require 'yasnippet)" in my .emacs file.  I've tried with and without "(yas-global-mode 1)" or "(yas-global-mode +1)" or "(yas-global-mode)" in my .emacs file
yas-reload-all doesn't help
yas-recompile-all doesnt help
Further, when I do "list-packages" yasnippets will change from "installed" to "dependency" even though there are no other packages installed.
I uninstalled emacs, did a clean reinstall and still the problem persists. Worse, it will occasionally work but next time I open emacs it breaks again.
Solved: Emacs was not going into LaTeX-mode when I opened .tex file because it was a blank .tex file. So yas didnt load the LaTeX table.

Please either (1) delete your question, if you think the solution was trivial/obvious or (2) post the solution as an answer, if you think the Q&A might help others. (You can accept your own answer.)

The diagnosis is incorrect: it does not matter if the file is blank or not - if there is an entry in auto-mode-alist matching the .tex suffix, the buffer should be in the specified mode.

Solved: Emacs was not going into LaTeX-mode when I opened .tex file because it was a blank .tex file. So yas didnt load the LaTeX table.

It does not matter if the file is blank, it only matters that the suffix .tex matches an entry in auto-mode-alist. If there is such an entry then the buffer should be in the specified mode. You should dig deeper.
